# Match phrases in Regex excluding keywords

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use Regex to return matches based on the follow criteria:

- Words containing special characters do not match.
- The keywords AND and OR do not match.
- Words with one space match and any words after this, for example -

  'lorem Ipsum is simply dummy AND text of the printing'

The above should return the following matches:

- lorem Ipsum
- Ipsum is
- is simply
- simply dummy
- text of
- of the
- the printing

I've been able to get the Regex to match every single word except for the keywords which is correct but its not capturing the whitespace. I've taken two similar approaches both with slightly different results:

This regex matches words and their spaces but the pattern does not continue onto the next word.

```
(\w*[^OR|^AND] [^OR|^AND]\w*)
```

The expression is very close but it doesn't return all of my desired matches as mentioned above, what am I missing?

Comment: I dont see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you use a negated character class `[^OR|^AND]` which will not match any of the listed characters so it will match any char except `ADNOR|^`

If [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) are supported, you could make use of combining a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right are 2 words and asserting using a negative lookahead that what is directly on the right is not either `OR` or `AND`.

To match the words you might match word characters using `\w+`

Your match will be in the first capturing group.

```
(?=(\b(?!(?:AND|OR)\b)\w+ (?!(?:AND|OR)\b)\w+\b))
```

Explanation

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `(` Capturing group 1

    - `\b(?!(?:AND|OR)\b)` Word boundary and assert what is directly on the right is not AND / OR
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars followed by a space
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

    - `(?:AND|OR)\b)\w+\b` Match AND / OR, then word boundary, 1+ word chars and word boundary
  - `)` Close first capturing group
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53Jr7K/1)